# Best way to store documents ( pdf , word ...) in a database ( postgres 9.4)

Tags: database, postgresql

**Problem :**

- To save documents such a pdf file or word...

**Approach :**

- but it seems to me not a good idea to store it directly in the database.
- I prefer to store only the address of the file in a column and to save the file itself on a folder beside my database.

**Todo :**

- Is there a trick to create a folder beside the database (mdf ldf) and to store the relativly to the mdf I mean (.. /document) for example?

Comment: i would recommended save path of document in DB instead of whole file

Comment: If you will store data outside database you need to remember about backups them independently + keep synchronized with DB. See also [Reasons in favor of storing files in the database](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/150787) Of course it always depends

Comment: thanks both for your answers , my idea it to store the path of the file  but like  lad2025  when the database would be moved I'll have a problem.
that it the target of my question

Comment: @xAmineX we will not save the whole physical path of directory under the application we should have one folder called `.../Doc/` under this folder we have our doc the path would be save in your DB like `Doc/doc1.pdf` and when you populate from DB you have to write a code on your programming language `Applicationpath + DBpath` then bring the Doc on Web

Comment: thanks think this is just what I want my question is can I integrate this folder with my database, cos I am programming an app in my computer that will be moved out to a local server.

Comment: If you store the documents in the file system you also need to make sure that you spread them over multiple directories. It's not a good idea to keep a million files in a single directory (even "thousands" are already a problem) Btw: there are no "mdf" or "ldf" file in Postgres

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after read all comments

suppose our website is `xyz.com/index.html` for Production and 
`xyz.com/Dev/index.html` for Development

under this application we would have one folder `/Doc` 
for production  `application path` would be `xyz.com/`
and Development `application path` would be `xyz.com/Dev/`

we will save the path in `DB table colummn` is `DOC/doc1.pdf` etc ...
when we bring the data from DB then we have to write a code on client end
that would be `application path + DB path in column`

for Production path would be `xyz.com/DOC/doc1.pdf` and
for Development path would be `xyz.com/Dev/DOC/doc1.pdf`
so you will get always right path to show your doc on websites