# Is it a good practice to save a base64 string on the Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, base64, storage

i'm developing an android application when the user can send a image to my webservice.

Currently on my WebService i get a Base64 string and save it in a table on my database.

**My question:** Is that a good practice? Because as far as i know the Base64 string is a heavy string. My concern is about the db performance, like when this table gets bigger than 10000...100000 records.
Or should i avoid this behavior?

Eg.: Isntead off store the Base64 string on the database, i could recover the image and save only the URL at my db.

Ps: The database is SqlServer

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: i hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32496440/

Comment: Why not to store raw images in database? Under this link you have description, pros/cons of such solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613898/storing-images-in-sql-server.

Comment: Zipped images in varbinary(MAX) ?

Comment: Thanks for the light @tinka

Comment: @ErikEj the images field is VARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: @GuiPabi am glad it helps you :)

Comment: @Fka that answer was very helpfull, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question, I think it's not good practice.

It depends largely upon how you will use these images you will probably load. Then, remember (**base64 encoding makes file sizes roughly 33% larger than their original binary representations**).
The best way would be writing the image and then saving its location in the database.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722603/storing-image-in-database-directly-or-as-base64-data) as it maybe help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MusicsCordova, after some research i save the images' location on the Database.

Answer (score 0):

i think using base64 encoding is very useful for saving URLs in the database. The big size for transmitted image is not good idea and not necessary.