# How to store php imagejpg() result in mysql database

Tags: php, image-processing, mysqli, php-gd

I have resized the image that I received from the user using the below code:

```
$imagedata = getimagesize($_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name']);
            $newwidth = $imagedata['0']/3;
            $newheight = $imagedata['1']/3; 
            $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name']);
            // Resize
            imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $imagedata['0'], $imagedata['1']);

            // Output and free memory
            ob_start();
            imagejpeg( $thumb );
            echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode(ob_get_clean()) . '">';
            imagedestroy($thumb);
```

now I am using this line

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode(ob_get_clean()) . '">';
```

to display the image but instead, I want to store it in my database.
I am not able to figure it out. I have searched in many forums and have failed to find any answer. 
Please help.

Comment: You are not include the db and insert query here. How should it insert?

Comment: @AnandPandey yes that code is there I haven't added it here and I know to how make a query and INSERT it into DB. The point here is how do I store it into DB as in what value do I sent in values. "INSERT  INTO db (image) VALUES (????)";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this by adding this line of code where echo is written:

```
$image = addslashes(ob_get_contents());
```

Now $image can be send normally to DB using query.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn’t store the image, what you can do is store the images in a known path and then store the unique id or name in the db, so then to retrieve you look for the id in the db and construct the path again.

[Is it a good practice to save a base64 string on the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630809/is-it-a-good-practice-to-save-a-base64-string-on-the-database)

Comment: I don't want to store it into DB as base64 that is the only way I have found on the web to convert it to viewable format through research. I want to know how can I store the result from imagejpeg() in MySQL DB as blob data type.

Comment: That's ok, have a look at this question maybe it help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052655/insert-blobs-in-mysql-databases-with-php

Comment: thanks but that is not my question. Thanks for the help though. if by any mean I am unclear through my question please let me know. I will try to describe it better.

Answer (score 0):

You don't store blobs unless you really, really have to.

Would you rather backup every day...

- a 100MB database and 50GB of files (differentially, using rsync)
- or a 50GB SQL database?